# How to use Python to create multiple dummy variables

Tags: python, pandas, sas, data-analysis

I am doing data analysis for Healthcare data. I was a SAS programmer and just start to learn Python coding. So I want to see if Python could take over some of my works in SAS and could make it more efficient with less amount of coding.

In the healthcare industry, we need to create dummy variables all the time. For example, I have a list of diagnosis codes for a different type of conditions, and I want to create dummy variables for each type of conditions. The value is 1 as long as a member has one of the diagnosis codes that associate with that condition type.

Here is the condition table looks like:

```
ICD10   Conditions
F1010   Alcohol_Abuse
F10129  Alcohol_Abuse
F1020   Alcohol_Abuse
F1120   Drug_Abuse
F1190   Drug_Abuse
F0630   Depression
```

And the claims data looks like:

```
Member ID       DX1           DX2              DX3
xxx1           F10129        F1010  
xxx1           F1010        
xxx2           F1010         F1020            F1120
xxx3           F0630        
xxx3           A5555
```

And the final results would look like:

```
Member ID   Alcohol_Abuse   Drug_Abuse  Depression
xxx1              1            0                 0
xxx2              1            1                 0
xxx3              0            0                 1
```

In SAS those works can be done fairly easily. 
First I create the first table as a format table (Basically just rename the variables ICD10 which is the variable that I want to use as a key to be "START" and rename the value that I want to show as "LABEL"):

```
DATA CONDITION; SET TABLE1; 
    FMTNAME = '$CONDITION'; 
        START = ICD10; 
        LABEL = CONDITIONS; 
    KEEP START HLO FMTNAME LABEL;
RUN;
PROC FORMAT CNTLIN = FMT.CANCER; RUN;
```

Then I will "apply" this format with the claim data (The PUT function is the way SAS apply format, it's like using SQL for TABLE2 left join TABLE1 with ICD10 or DX as the key and keep all the variables both tables have):

```
DATA CLAIM_FLAG; SET TABLE2;
    IF PUT(DX1, $CONDITION.) = 'Alcohol_Abuse' OR PUT(DX2, $CONDITION.) = 'Alcohol_Abuse' OR PUT(DX3, $CONDITION.) = 'Alcohol_Abuse' 
    THEN Alcohol_Abuse = 1; ELSE Alcohol_Abuse = 0;
    ... (same logic for the other conditions)
RUN;
```

Eventually I aggregate the CLAIM_FLAG data into member level, which means each member would only have 1 row (I skip the SAS code for that part).

This is what I have been tried so far in Python (But you don't need to follow what I been done):

```
df1 = data[['Member ID', 'DX1']].rename(columns={"DX1":"ICD10"})
df2 = data[['Member ID', 'DX2']].rename(columns={"DX2":"ICD10"})
df3 = data[['Member ID', 'DX3']].rename(columns={"DX3":"ICD10"})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).drop_duplicates()
icd_df = df.merge(lookup, on='ICD10', how='left')
```

It would be really helpful if someone could provide a Python program that could first import a EXCEL file that like TABLE1 and then create dummy variables and aggregate into member level like the final output show.   Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could use a dictionary and assign each code to an integer then loop through the  member IDs to fill your dataframe

Comment: This question is too broad as currently posed, and also doesn't well define what the desired result is.  (Both of these are reasons why questions are routinely closed).  What is your desired result?  Do you want to write to a database?  Create a spreadsheet?  Drive some code logic?  You should provide more information, and also as @minterm suggests, show us what effort you've put into this so far.  If you don't know Python well enough to even get started, then you should find another forum to help you with that or find a good book or tutorial.  Understanding your tools is always a first step.

Comment: Hi, @minterm. I have tried using Python is by stack all 3 DX column into 1 single column and then using left join to add those conditions. And I am thinking the next would be somehow transposed condition column into multiple dummy columns.

Comment: Hi, @Steve. Thanks for your suggestion. I added some more detail and my desired results would be the 3rd table shows. By using SAS, I could import any excel file as long as it's the same as 1st table shows (the left column contains values and the right column contain dummy variable name) and output the final results.  I am wondering if Python could do the same thing.

Comment: The question also missing correct tags. On SAS side you are using Base SAS but for python it is not standard library there must be some third party Modul i suspect pandas.

Comment: Also in standard python there is no need for dummy variables depending of what you doing with you variables you would be better with dictionary and/or sets.